# Chrome Back button issues

Tags: ee2

Whenever a user hits the back button in Google Chrome, if the previous page was password protected - it asks the user to login again even though they already are. Refreshing the page does display the protected content, but this is not a great experience.

Anyone else experiencing anything similar with the last couple Chrome releases?

Comment: Do you mean password-protected with HTTP authentication?

Comment: I would say this is the expected behavior. The back button should take you back one step in your history. It should show you what you *were* looking at. If it did a refresh, the content might be different to what you were seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a member login area in the front-end templates or in the control panel? I'm using the latest version of Chrome and I don't have that problem with either.

It sounds like a session or cookie problem. In Admin > Security & Privacy > Security & Sessions, what do you have your Control Panel Session and User Session set to?

Try this:

[image]